# Error in prediction in ROCR "Number of cross-validation runs must be equal for predictions and labels."

Tags: r

I am trying to use prediction function but there is one which is not allowing me to use it.

```
pred <- predict(decision_tree, test_data, type = "prob") 

head(pred)
head(my_data)
tail(pred)
tail(test_data$Income)
pred <- prediction(pred, test_data$Income)
evalu <- performance(pred, "acc")

pred <- predict(decision_tree, test_data, type = "prob") 

head(pred)
head(my_data)
tail(pred)
tail(test_data$Income)
pred <- prediction(pred, test_data$Income)
evalu <- performance(pred, "acc")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in prediction(pred, test_data$Income) : 
  Number of cross-validation runs must be equal for predictions and labels.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I hope you worked around in the meantime. For all the others searching for the answer: https://arulvelkumar.wordpress.com/2017/09/03/prediction-function-in-r-number-of-cross-validation-runs-must-be-equal-for-predictions-and-labels/
In short: simply add a [,2] after your line:
pred <- predict(decision_tree, test_data, type = "prob") [,2] and it should work.

Regards
Matthias

Comment: Hi Matthias. Welcome to S.O! Thank you for this helpful answer. Could you please edit it so that it starts with a comprehensive solution to the problem? Linking to external sources can be helpful, but answers are expected to make sense without any external reference.

Comment: You can add backticks (\`) to format inline code. For example, \`2+2\` becomes `2+2`

Comment: Finally, please remove strictly unnecessary text such as 'Regards Matthias' and 'I hope you worked around in the meantime'. Those sentiments are welcomed and encouraged here, but answers should generally be limited to content which is strictly informative. This can feel slightly odd at first, but you get used to it - it's just the style we use to ensure that information is formal and accessible. Imagine you're writing something more like an encyclopaedia than an email. Again, thank you. This is a great contribution.